# How to preserve scroll between pages by using localStorage to store screenY, pageY and offsetY?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, local-storage

My objective is to preserve the scrolling position on a collection page of many image cards (divided in 3 rows). When a person leaves the page (by clicking on one of the image cards), then goes back to the collection page, the top part of the image clicked must be under a header of 150px.

My problems are:

1. How do I offset the page by 150px so that the scroll is preserved
   under the header?
2. How do I get the top of the image to show
   instead of where I clicked on the image block? Let's say the image's
   height is 400px and I clicked at height 350px, I'd like the full
   image to show instead of the remaining 50px.

I've used the browser's localStorage to store the screenY, pageY, offsetY of the click event to preserve the scroll position. On page load, it brings the pageY to the top of the page. I have not utilized screenY or offsetY in my code.

javascript, jquery:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {

        //On Click in the PLP, store position of mouse
        $('#plp').on('click', function(event) {
            const positionClick = {
                screenY: event.screenY,
                pageY: event.pageY,
                offsetY: event.offsetY
            }
            $(event.target).attr("id", "target");
            window.localStorage.setItem('positionClick', JSON.stringify(positionClick));
        });

        //On page load
        function load() {
            var position = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('positionClick'));
            var target_pageY = position.pageY;
            var target_offsetY = position.offsetY;
            window.scrollTo({top: target_pageY, behavior: 'smooth'});
        }
        window.onload = load;
    });
</script>
```

html structure:

```
<body>
<main>
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="plp">
    <div class="plp-list">
      <div class="plp-products">
        <span id="filter">
          <div>
            <div><a href><img /></a></div>
            <div><a href><img /></a></div>
            <div><a href><img /></a></div>
            <div><a href><img /></a></div>
            <div><a href><img /></a></div>
            <div><a href><img /></a></div>
            <div><a href><img /></a></div>
          </div>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

An example of the behavior I'm looking for is on Zara's collection website. If you click on any product and back, the product is at the top of the page regardless of where you clicked on the image. 
https://www.zara.com/ca/en/woman-new-in-l1180.html?v1=1281662

Comment: Is this code your contribution to solving the problem? Does it solve the problem? Does it run at all or gives you any errors? BTW, your html `span` tag was never closed.

Comment: @UdoE. Thanks for pointing it out. Right now, the code brings the pageY to the top of the page on page load (using localStorage's saved keys that was stored on click). I have not utilized screenY or offsetY in my code to position the top of the image, under the #header.